# ocaml type error with generic list type (ide * 'a)

Tags: expression, ocaml, typeerror, interpreter

I am coding an OCaml interpreter and I would check if there are duplicate inside a list of pairs.

```
type exp = ... | Dict of (ide * exp) list | AddPair of exp * (ide * exp) list;;
type evT = ... | DictVal of (ide * evT) list


Dict(pairs) -> 
             if invariant pairs then DictVal(evalDictList pairs r) 
             else failwith("The Dictionary has multiple copy of the same key")|

AddPair(dict, newpair) ->
             (match (eval dict r) with
                DictVal (oldpairs) -> let evalnewpair = evalDictList newpair r in
                                                if invariant (evalnewpair@oldpairs) then DictVal(oldpairs@evalnewpair)
                                                else failwith ("A new key has the same value as another already inserted")|
                            _ -> failwith ("not a dictionary"))|

and evalDictList (pairs : (ide * exp) list) (r : evT env) : (ide * evT) list = match pairs with
                [ ] -> [ ] |
                (key,value) :: other -> (key, eval value r) :: evalDictList other r;;
```

and the invariant:

```
and invariant (pairs : (ide * 'a) list) : bool = match pairs with
        [ ] -> true |
        (key,value) :: other -> if lookfor key other then invariant other else false
```

The error:
**This expression has type (ide * evT) list
       but an expression was expected of type (ide * exp) list
       Type evT is not compatible with type exp**

In "Dict" invariat use a list of (ide * exp) while in "AddPair" 
 invariant will get evalnewpair@oldpairs where evalnewpair has type (ide * evT) and oldpairs (ide * evT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `invariant` is part of a mutually recursive function definition, you need to be explicit with the universal quantification:

```
and invariant: 'a.  (ide * 'a) list -> bool = fun l -> ...
```

In your case, it might be simpler to split off `invariant` from the mutually recursive block.

Comment: But this would get the same parameters, the problem is what I give to invariant as parameter

Comment: No, the two type annotations are meaningfully different and this difference matters inside mutually recursive function definition. Note also that you should try give a fully contained example and the exact error.

Comment: I changed the post

Comment: Your example is still not self-contained. However, after fixing the holes, I reiterate that your problem is the imprecise annotation on invariants and adding an explicit universal annotations fixes the error that you mention.